# Chrome can't download a link from a file on AWS S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

Currently I'm using .NET to generate a presigned URL for a file I upload on S3, after I get the URL I send and email to the client with an anchor tag in it pointing to the generate URL and letting them know that the file is ready to download.
The problem is that whenever I click on the link, chrome tries to open a new tab for a few seconds and then closes that new tab without really triggering a download. It does work with other browsers or even if I copy the link and open a new tab myself and paste it there then the download starts...

Any ideas as to what could be happening here?

Comment: On same machine it works with one browser but not another?    We need to determine if it is the machine or the type of browser.

Comment: tested on several machines all have this behavior when downloading from Chrome... so I believe it could be browser specific

Comment: What is displaying the link? Gmail does sneaky redirects using javascript on email links (this is to harvest out-click data... this is not immediately apparent when hovering the link) via https://www.google.com/url . Could this be an issue? Perhaps an ad-blocker?

Comment: A debugging proxy server such as Fiddler or Charles might help you to gather more info about what chrome is up to.

Comment: Are you using latest version of Chrome?

Comment: I think this is not related just to .net and c#. I also have this problem using ruby on rails. The problem is specific to chrome + gmail + redirection to s3 download. (possibly any download)

Comment: Fails for Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (x86_64)
and for  Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: Any solution here, please? I agree with the opinion that this is a browser-related issue and opening the S3 link manually does the download.  

Also, the working response contains: `content-type: application/octet-stream`

While the failing one: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we created a route in our application where you can download the s3 file via our app not directly from the browser.

I believe the reason that Chrome does not allow this to happen is security thus if you move the downloading part to your server will solve the issue.